# Preventing changesets with files matching .hgignore patterns from being pushed to an hg repo

Tags: mercurial, acl, hgignore, mercurial-hook

How can I prevent changesets (from the source repo) with files matching `.hgignore` patterns (in the head of each respective target branch in the target repo) from being pushed to an hg repo?

It looks like the ACL Extension can deny pushes based on file name globs, but I prefer to keep `[acl.deny]` in `hgrc` in sync with `.hgignore`.

Can the ACL Extension read `.hgignore`, and use it to specify file selectors for `[acl.deny]`?

If not, is there any existing script to sync `.hgignore` patterns to `[acl.deny]`?

Is there any other way to achieve this (other than manual syncing)?